# Frozen modules warning and looping script when running multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, loops, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, iteration

I'm trying to make a Python program iterate through pixels in parallel to speed up the process. The working version of my program calls `GetPixelData()` in a for loop with the arguments `x_pos, x_size, y_size, pixel_number`, `pixel_number` being incremented by the for loop so the program can process the next pixel.

This does the job, but slowly (even though the script only processes about 40 pixels at most). I'm using this to automate a very high-latency online game so every millisecond counts. My solution was to use a multiprocessing Pool to run a function on each pixel in parallel, while keeping an iteration variable to pass to the function so it knows which pixel it should process.

However, every time I run my script, I get this in the Python debugger:

```
0.02s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
```

After that, the script starts looping on top of itself, opening tab after tab on Chrome.

Here's the function code:

```python
def GetPixelData(x_pos, x_size, y_size, pixel_number, pixels_obstacle, pixels_coffee):
    global coffee_amount

    x = pixel_number / x_size
    y = pixel_number % y_size

    if pixels_obstacle.getpixel((x, y))[2] < 240:
        Jump(driver, canvas)
        print("Object")
    elif pixels_coffee.getpixel((x, y))[1] < 50:
        Jump(driver, canvas)
        coffee_amount += 1
        print("+1 Coffee (" + str(coffee_amount) + " total)")
    
    return x, y
```

And here's how I'm calling the function in parallel:

```python
# Get pixels in bounds
bounds_obstacle = (x_pos, 830, x_pos + x_size, 830 + y_size) * screen_multiplier
bounds_coffee = (x_pos, 460, x_pos + x_size, 460 + y_size) * screen_multiplier
pixels_obstacle = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=bounds_obstacle)
pixels_coffee = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=bounds_coffee)

# Process pixels in parallel
args = [x_pos, x_size, y_size, pixels_obstacle, pixels_coffee]
iterable = ([args, pixel_number] for pixel_number in range(x_size * y_size))
pixel_pool = pool.Pool(os.cpu_count())
for r in pixel_pool.imap_unordered(GetPixelData, iterable):
    print(str(r))
```

Comment: That sounds like you have top-level code outside of an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block, which is required by `multiprocessing`.

Comment: I'm assuming this code is using PIL - is that correct? The standard advice about speeding up this kind of code is that if you can turn it into numpy array manipulation, it will be faster than if you use multiprocessing. So e.g. if you do `np.array(pixels_obstacle)`, you can extract a specific color band very quickly, or compare every pixel with 50 very quickly.

Comment: @NickODell This is using Pillow. I'm trying the numpy array out now but how would I get the value of a channel in a pixel in the array?

Comment: If you wanted to get every value of red in an array, where it's in RGB format, you could do that with `array[:, :, 0]` to select the first band of every pixel. You can then do `array[:, :, 0] < 10` to find every red pixel which is less than 10, or `(array[:, :, 0] < 10).mean()` to find the proportion of pixels with red values less than 10. You see what I mean?

Comment: I'm assuming the two colons in the array indices are the coordinates of the pixel, right? For some reason it doesn't like when I replace them with `x` and `y`: `only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Comment: Note that your code is currently sending a copy of both images for every pixel you process...  Learning how to use numpy effectively would make things thousands of times faster than what you've got now.